# problem adding linearlayout after listview

Tags: android

i am the new android development.i got one problem i.e. in my application i added listview for the activity.after listview i added one linear layout in that i took one imageview and textview.my problem is for this one it cannot show the last row in the emulator but it displays the imageview and textview.but its not displaying the last row of the listview.i cannot understand what is the problem having so can you know please help my xml code is below see it once....


    
        
            
            
        
          -->

```
        <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/search_layout"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal">
            <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autocomplete_country"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="Search"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"> -->
        <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/search_layout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:layout_above="@+id/ban_layout"/>

         <!-- </ScrollView> -->

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- </ScrollView> -->
    <!-- <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> -->

    <!-- </RelativeLayout> -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/listview"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:id="@+id/ban_layout">
    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/orbit"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="60dip" 
            android:gravity="center"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because the your linear layout [ban_layout] is covering up your listview, as you have set it to align towards the bottom of the parent.

Quick Hacks,

Add an extra row and set its inside elements to invisible in your listview adapter

or

Add an bottom margin to your listview that compensates the footer

Your best solution would be to rework the parent relativelayout and set up a linearlayouts with weights